# Are Interstitial ads broken? iOS 8?

Tags: ios, iad

I created  a dummy sprite kit app.
I then added the most rudimentary interstitial iAd support.

In `AppDelegate.m/didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
[UIViewController prepareInterstitialAds];
```

In `ViewController.m/ViewDidLoad`

```
self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyManual;
```

Then after presenting the scene, I added a continuous loop to invoke ads.

```
[scene runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:
    [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:3.0],
    [SKAction runBlock:^
        {
            if( !self.isPresentingFullScreenAd )
                [super requestInterstitialAdPresentation];
        }
    ]]]]
];
```

It doesn't work what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running on the iPhone 4s? If so try switching to 5/6 in the simulator or in real life and it works!

Easy to replicate.

I've logged a bug with Apple.

The other issue I've faced in the past, especially for new iTunesConnect accounts, is that you need to complete all of the outstanding banking and iAd contracts in iTunes Connect, even for a free App.

Also, sometimes ads aren't served to the simulator (try restarting the app).

Also, if you look at Settings in the Simulator you can change the fill-rate of ads and if infinite ads are provided (and more).

All can be contributing factors.

Comment: I thought Interstatial ads were only for iPad?

Comment: Nope, they've been in the iPhone for a while. Before I upgraded to 8.2 they were working on the iPhone 4s.

Comment: Oh. I thought I read something in the documentation that they were only for iPad. Then again, the iAd documentation is a bit outdated. It shows code that was depreciated in iOS 6.

Comment: See this http://appleinsider.com/articles/14/08/26/apple-rolls-out-full-screen-interstitial-pre-roll-video-iads